# Python ast.literal_eval() not working

Tags: python, sqlite, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm taking a string list from a sqlite3 database and i'm trying to convert the string list into an actual
 list data type.

```
print(all_houses)
print(type(all_houses))
houses=[]
for h in all_houses:
    temp=[]
    h1=h['imgLocations']
    print(h1)
    print(type(h1))
    # converts string list to real list
    h1 = ast.literal_eval(h1)
    print(h1)
    print(type(h1))
```

I get this error.

```
    File "C:\Users\Matt\Google Drive\HeritageEstates_website\views.py", line 410, in preown
h1 = ast.literal_eval(h1)
File "C:\Users\Matt\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 46, in literal_eval
node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
File "C:\Users\Matt\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
File "<unknown>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

This is all the print statements it made

```
 [{'visible': 1, 'hPrice': 123, 'imgLocations': "['C:\\Users\\riger\\Google Drive\\HeritageEstates_website\\images//asdasd.jpg']", 'hDesc': '1 bedroom'}, {'visible': 1, 'hPrice': 124124, 'imgLocations': "['C:\\Users\\riger\\Google Drive\\HeritageEstates_website\\images//Keyboard.JPG']", 'hDesc': '1231'}, {'visible': 1, 'hPrice': 123, 'imgLocations': "['C:\\Users\\riger\\Google Drive\\HeritageEstates_website\\images//me.jpg']", 'hDesc': '123'}]
<class 'list'>
['C:\Users\riger\Google Drive\HeritageEstates_website\images//asdasd.jpg']
<class 'str'>
```

I did the same thing on another website and it works. I also have `import ast`

I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: Your string is not the proper `repr` of a list. The backslashes within the string are escaped once, but they need to be escaped twice in order for the string to be valid.

Comment: It's throwing that error because the string contains `\U` which is a unicode escape symbol. Try typing this to see: `x = '\UHelloWorld'`. Basically, if you can't save the string as a variable, then `ast.literal_eval()` won't do it either. A solution is to change it to raw string`x = r'\UHelloWorld'`. But, I don't know how you could do that in your code, so I cant provide a full answer. Good luck though.